How to download Excel file dynamically in a REST Controller?
We are migrating our session based application to REST APIs. In our current application, downloading small excel files dynamically by writing generated excel work book to OutputStream which we get from HttpResponse object. Below is the current code to download excel.
@RequestMapping(value = "exportRules", method = GET)
public void exportRuleResults(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) 
{

    try {
            
    final SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
    // summary report
    final Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Rules Details");
            
                        //Headers (First row of report)
            final int rows = writeRulesHeaders(workbook, sheet);
            int pageNumber = 0;
            final ExportReturnVals ret = new ExportReturnVals(1, true);
            ret.rowIndex = rows;
            ret.totalnumberOfRecords = 1;

            while (ret.hasMoreRows) {
                writeRows(pageNumber, sheet, ret, workbook);
                pageNumber++;
            }
            OutputStream os=getOutputStream(response, ret);
            workbook.write(os);
            response.flushBuffer();
            workbook.dispose();
            os.close();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
}

private OutputStream getOutputStream(final HttpServletResponse response, final   ExcelExportReturnVals ret) throws IOException {

    final OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    OutputStream outputStream;

    if (ret.totalnumberOfRecords > MAX_RECORD_NONZIP) {
        response.setContentType("application/zip");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + "RuleDetails" + ".zip\"");
        outputStream = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(os));
        ((ZipOutputStream) outputStream).putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("RuleDetails" + ".xlsx"));
    }else {
    response.setContentType("application/xlsx");
    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + "RuleDetails" + ".xlsx\"");
    outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
    }
    return outputStream;
}

How to achieve this ( without saving file to temporary path and downloading dynamically) using REST API where we can not use HTTP Response object?

Please could you specify which framework you want to use for your REST API.

We are using Angular and Spring.

Do you mean you want to use @RestController as here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-vs-restcontroller#spring-mvc-rest-controller

Yes, we do use @RestController annotation for controller classes.

Return a ResponseEntity<byte[]> as described by Baeldung.
Something like this:
    @GetMapping(value = "exportRules")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> exportRuleResults()
    {

        try {

            final SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
            // summary report
            final Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Rules Details");

            //Headers (First row of report)
            final int rows = writeRulesHeaders(workbook, sheet);
            int pageNumber = 0;
            final ExportReturnVals ret = new ExportReturnVals(1, true);
            ret.rowIndex = rows;
            ret.totalnumberOfRecords = 1;

            while (ret.hasMoreRows) {
                writeRows(pageNumber, sheet, ret, workbook);
                pageNumber++;
            }
            ByteArrayBuilder byteArrayBuilder = new ByteArrayBuilder();
            workbook.write(byteArrayBuilder);
            byteArrayBuilder.flush();
            workbook.dispose();
            HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            httpHeaders.add("Content-type", "application/xlsx");
            return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(byteArrayBuilder.toByteArray(), httpHeaders, HttpStatusCode.valueOf(200));
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }



tried your answer, but getting below error. Please suggest.                                             ERROR [http] - No converter for [class [B] with preset Content-Type 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class [B] with preset Content-Type 'application/vnd.ms-excel'

Could you try going back to 'application/xlsx' then? I will edit my answer. Although I will also investigate at my end.

I haven't been able to reproduce your error message with either media type. Here is a web page about it https://www.baeldung.com/spring-no-converter-with-preset. It seems that I have an HttpMessageConverter that can cope with byte arrays while you haven't for some reason. I am not sending a valid Excel file in my test but I don't think that will make a difference. Still thinking about it.

yes, tried with content type:"application/xlsx" and produces with values like MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE and MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, but no luck.

I have reproduced this error by removing the ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter from the list of messageConverters added by WebMvcConfigurationSupport#addDefaultHttpMessageConverters. Do you have org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web in your dependencies?

More digging has unearthed the fact that WebMvcConfigurationSupport#addDefaultHttpMessageConverters is triggered by the  EnableWebMvcConfiguration being available as a Configuration to scan, so it should work if you have org.springframework:spring-webmvc as a dependency and @SpringBootApplication on your main class.

not using spring boot. just used class based configuration.

I think you need to make sure that org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter is available as a bean in your SpringContext and that it is injected into whatever implementation of AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor is involved in your processing your responses. I hope it will be auto-injected once it is a bean, so do you think you could try creating it as @Bean on one of your configurations, or include it in the XML if you're using XML for your spring config?

And if this doesn't work, please could you post the pom.xml and the main class and pom.xml of your solution in the original question?

tried by adding org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter bean like below '@Bean public ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter byteArrayMessageConverter() { return new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter(); }` but no luck.

Oh well, if you post your spring configuration, pom & main class I can have a further look.

apologies for late response.  I am not able to add pom.xml to my question as it is exceeding the limited characters. Is there any other way to add?

I don't know, aside from setting up a github repo or gist. I have been trying to replicate this outside of Spring Boot but it doesn't seem easy to get anything working without Spring Boot these days - all the examples have gone to Spring Boot.
